# Netbeans text editor missing

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I installed Netbeans7.4 on Ubuntu.

When I create my Java project I have only "history editor" installed.
There is no code editor, so I cannot do anything to my code.

Do someone have any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Btw. did you install Netbeans through packages or downloading from netbeans website?

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to **Source** just below the tab of your file (upper-left corner, left of *"History"*). If this is not available, can you please post a screenshot of your window?

Here's a image of the view (Source: netbeans.org):

[image: Editor window (java)]

Please see the selected *Source*, above the linenumbers. You can switch between Source and History here.